# create Container with smooth sides like image (see attached image) in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

see below image

[image]

I want create a container(or other widget) with custom shape that like same as image.
I don't want create content in that, just shape of that.
This isn't BorderRadius, because those sides is curved.(I want create this sides like that image).

Thank you

Comment: I prefer that implemented without CustomPaint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can create that ui with figma_squircle: ^0.5.3 .

Answer (score 2):

You can use [CustomPain](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html) to draw your own container. You will need some math and geometry knowledge.
Most people avoid to use `CustomPain`, they offently use an Image as a background, thats simple and easer way.

UPDATE: im not good in math soo i, use this [tool](https://shapemaker.web.app/) to draw a shape and generate `CustomPaint`, i know this is not a good way but thats only way i can help.

```dart
class RPSCustomPainter extends CustomPainter{
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
  Paint paint0 = Paint()
      ..color = const Color.fromARGB(255, 33, 150, 243)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 1.0;
     
    Path path0 = Path();
    path0.moveTo(size.width*0.0012500,size.height*0.5000000);
    path0.cubicTo(size.width*0.0015625,size.height*0.3020000,size.width*0.0378125,size.height*0.1620000,size.width*0.1250000,size.height*0.1000000);
    path0.cubicTo(size.width*0.2462500,size.height*0.0020000,size.width*0.7525000,size.height*0.0020000,size.width*0.8750000,size.height*0.1000000);
    path0.cubicTo(size.width*0.9612500,size.height*0.1660000,size.width*0.9987500,size.height*0.3040000,size.width,size.height*0.5000000);
    path0.cubicTo(size.width*0.9987500,size.height*0.6960000,size.width*0.9587500,size.height*0.8340000,size.width*0.8750000,size.height*0.9000000);
    path0.cubicTo(size.width*0.7512500,size.height*0.9985000,size.width*0.2456250,size.height*0.9960000,size.width*0.1250000,size.height*0.9020000);
    path0.cubicTo(size.width*0.0384375,size.height*0.8400000,size.width*0.0009375,size.height*0.6960000,size.width*0.0012500,size.height*0.5000000);
    path0.close();
    canvas.drawPath(path0, paint0);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

[image]

Comment: hi, can you give me a code for that, please?

Comment: @ImanGhasemiArani check the UPDATED

Comment: thank you for your answer. but, if i change the size of that, i should refactor that, and this way is seems difficult.

Comment: @ImanGhasemiArani if you good in math and geometry, you can solve it easy. I recomend you to use an Image as background

Comment: @ImanGhasemiArani `Path` have many function to draw, not only cubic.

Comment: I answer that Q.